# Converting MapSource gdb files to CSV with GPSBabel - stop waypoint names being replaced by waypoint comments

Tags: convert, csv, gpsbabel

I have multiple .gdb files that I convert to CSV files using a .bat file in Windows. A simplified version is below:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.gdb) DO "C:\Program Files\GPSBabel\GPSBabel" -w -i gdb -f %%i -x nuketypes,routes,tracks -o csv -F %%~Ni_convertedfile.csv
```

This mostly works, but where waypoints in the gdb file (viewing in MapSource) have a comment as well as a waypoint name, the output CSV file replaces the waypoint name with the comment.

For example, in this gdb file there are three waypoints
[image]

Ideally, I want the CSV file to appear like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -24.20577 | 30.78244 | 0650SB |
| -24.20597 | 30.7818 | 0705 |
| -24.20602 | 30.78173 | 0720 |

But instead, it appears like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -24.20577 | 30.78244 | 01-JAN-13 6:50:22 |
| -24.20597 | 30.7818 | 01-JAN-13 7:05:12 |
| -24.20602 | 30.78173 | 720 |

Only the third waypoint has the waypoint name because it has no additional comment. The leading zero is also lost, which I would ideally also like to keep in the waypoint names. Is there a way to ensure GPSbabel formats the data how I would like? Ideally with the bat file, but I'm open to any other suggestions.

Comment: Is this "gdb file" an Esri file geodatabase (`.gdb` *directory*) or something else?

Comment: I think so; they are .gdb files, created originally from Garmin's programme MapSource. I've now provided an answer to the problem; thank you for the potential help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to the GPSBabel mailing list, I've been told the solution: converting the file to a .unicsv file rather than a csv file provides all the fields from the .gdb files in separate columns.

```
-o unicsv -F %%~Ni_convertedfile.unicsv
```

The issue with dropping leading zeros turns out to be due to Excel formatting them as numbers and removing the zeros. Opening the file in Notepad retains the leading zeros.